# Can I have Mutual/2 Way SSL without having https connection?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am very new to this SSL configurations. I am working on adding 2 way ssl configuration on a Springboot application. I have gone through lot of code snippets online on this implementation.

My destination server end point - https://endpoint.com/path/to/service is secured to which I make a REST call.

If I set my application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 9001
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    client-auth: need
    key-store: classpath:KEYSTORE.pfx
    key-store-password: password
    key-alias: aliasname
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    trust-store: classpath:TRUSTSTORE.p12
    trust-store-password: password
    trust-store-type: PKCS12
```

My application runs on **https**://localhost:9001.

TRUSTSTORE.p12 contains the server's public certificates and CA certificates.

With this setup, I'm able to get response from the server using RestTemplate configurations.
When I give another TrustStore which doesn't have my Server's public Certificate, it fails to establish a connection - Expected behaviour.

But when I disable the SSL:

```
server:
      port: 9001
      ssl:
        enabled: false
```

My application runs on HTTP//:localhost:9001.

Will I still be able to make a Mutual authentication with the truststore and keystore available at my SSL Context?
Can I Still validate the server's public certificate with the above yml configuration and the below code?

```
    // KeyStore and TrustStore
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
            ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("KEYSTORE.pfx");
            InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream();
            keyStore.load(inputStream, "password".toCharArray());

            TS = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
            ClassPathResource classPathResource1 = new ClassPathResource("TRUSTSTORE.p12");
            InputStream inputStream1 = classPathResource1.getInputStream();
            TS.load(inputStream1, "password".toCharArray());

// configuring the SSLContext
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(TS, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                            .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray()).build());
```

NOTE: With ssl set to FALSE other applications would call my endpoint at http//:localhost:9001. And I would make a REST call the server on https://endpoint.com/path/to/service.

Comment: what does cURL -v output when you try the encrypted endpoint?

Comment: Misleading title. The answer to the questiuon in your title is 'yes', because you can just use TLS directly, but that's not what you're really asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have mutual SSL authentication without having SSL. While one might probably construct some kind of mutual authentication method which works with plain HTTP instead of HTTPS there is no standard for this. The usual certificate based mutual authentication which is implemented in the browsers works only with HTTPS since it is actually part of the SSL layer.